# Why Kruskal Algorithm has to iterate all edges?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

So here is the pseudocode of Kruskal from Wiki

```
algorithm Kruskal(G) is
F:= ∅
for each v ∈ G.V do
    MAKE-SET(v)
for each (u, v) in G.E ordered by weight(u, v), increasing do
    if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v) then
        F:= F ∪ {(u, v)}
        UNION(FIND-SET(u), FIND-SET(v))
return F
```

I'm just wondering why the algo cannot stop as long as F.size=|V|-1? Why it still needs to go over all edge? Thanks!

Comment: Whilst I can't divine what a wikipedia contributor was thinking when they wrote that: I would guess it was to keep the pseudocode as simple as possible. It doesn't have to terminate early, so it doesn't. There's no general rule about whether the edges with greatest weight will or will not be in a spanning tree, so there's no change to asymptotic run-time based on the early exit. The 'Algorithm' section of the wikipedia article you reference _does_ explicitly mention that as an option - "while S is nonempty and F is not yet spanning", you can exit early if you want to.

Comment: If the graph is not connected then your check will never be fulfilled, and all edges will have to be exhausted.

Comment: The question is based on a flawed premise - Kruskal's algorithm does not have to keep going after n-1 edges are added, it's just that you found an implementation which does keep going.

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is not connected then your check will never be fulfilled, and all edges will have to be exhausted to find that there is no connection.

See this nice animation from Wikipedia, if the last two sets are not connected Kruskal will not detect it until all edges are tried.

[image]

So if the graph is connected an extra early out could help, and might significantly decrease runtime.

Comment: This does not explain why you can not terminate as soon as you find N-1 edges to add your spanning tree.

Comment: @unlut I would only find N-2 if there are two unconnected parts of the graph.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I am not saying terminate ONLY when you found N-1 edges, the question is saying it should be an extra early exit condition.

Comment: @unlut Updated so that it both explains why you can't always get out early and acknowledge it could exit early.